# BigQuery - streaming large datasets vs quotas

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Data in question has a block of `repeated` columns. This set of values can get very long. As a result Im hitting `Maximum allowed row size exceeded` errors.

Is there a strategy for breaking up entries like these such that they will be under the 1Mb per-row streaming quota but somehow end up together?